# transparent padding in overflow menu in Jellybean

Tags: android, android-toolbar, overflow-menu, android-4.1-jelly-bean

Im having a problem with the overflow menu in my device running API 16 Jellybean.
As you can see in the photo below it is rendered with transparent padding. I run the default Blank Activity of Android studio after creating a new project with a minsdk of API 16 and targetsdk of API 23 and this is how the overflow menu looks like. I hope someone can tell me why is this happening.

[screenshot] 
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po4Ht.png)

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but you appear to have a problem with that nine-patch image. If you are using gradle plugin 2.2.0-alpha2, it has broken something in the way AAPT processes nine-patches, so you should downgrade that back to something older (like 2.1.0)

Comment: Might be a device specific issue....possibly something only seen in tablets....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Karakuri, your answer solved my problem. I did upgrade to gradle plugin 2.2.0-alpha2 recently and I didn't notice this issue because I was always testing using my other device running API 22. So downgrading it to 2.1.0 solve this issue.